# Inconsistent loading symbols / design when refreshing feed

Tags: discussion, android-app, android-app-feed

As seen in the screenshot below:

- left: triggered by clicking the Feed menu at the left bar
- right: triggered by Pull to Refresh in the feed

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I see an issue.  The two pacifiers serve two distinct purposes - one is actively loading content; the other is refreshing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two loading symbols when refreshing a feed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192223/two-loading-symbols-when-refreshing-a-feed)