# Two loading symbols when refreshing a feed

Tags: discussion, android-app, android-app-feed

In relation to [my previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192025/inconsistent-loading-symbols-design-when-refreshing-feed), I found out it's possible to have two loading symbols when refreshing the page.

What I did was:

1. Click the Feed menu from the left bar, and
2. Quickly pull down to refresh

[image]

Comment: So maybe you want to delete your previous question?  Or add this answer to it, because this particular post isn't really a question at all.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I think they are separate concerns.